# GraphQL "Float cannot represent non numeric value: Infinity"

Tags: mongodb, graphql

I'm currently migrating a site from REST to graphql and I have a query that accepts a 'period' argument

```
valuations(period: $period) {
 low
}
```

In my resolvers im making an aggregate call to mongodb timeseries based on the period to return a certain timeframe of results.

```
  valuations: async ({ collectible_id }, { period }, { prisma }) => {
        switch (true){
            case period === 1:
                return [await CollectiblePrice.aggregate([
                    {
                        "$match": {
                            collectibleId: collectible_id,
                            "date": {
                                $gte: new Date(new Date().getTime() - (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000))
                            }
                        }
                    },
                ])]
            case period === 2:
                return [await CollectiblePrice.aggregate([
                    {
                        "$match": {
                            collectibleId: collectible_id,
                            "date": {
                                $gte: new Date(new Date().getTime() - (48 * 60 * 60 * 1000))
                            }
                        }
                    },
                ])]
            case period === 7:
                console.log('7 day period...')
                return [await CollectiblePrice.aggregate([
                    {
                        "$match": {
                            collectibleId: collectible_id,
                            "date": {
                                $gte: new Date(new Date().getTime() - (7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000))
                            }
                        }
                    },
                ])]
            case period === 28 || 30:
                return [await CollectiblePrice.aggregate([
                    {
                        "$match": {
                            collectibleId: collectible_id,
                            "date": {
                                $gte: new Date(new Date().getTime() - (30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000))
                            }
                        }
                    },
                ])]
            case period === 90:
                return [await CollectiblePrice.aggregate([
                    {
                        "$match": {
                            collectibleId: collectible_id,
                            "date": {
                                $gte: new Date(new Date().getTime() - (90 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000))
                            }
                        }
                    },
                ])]
            default:
                return [await CollectiblePrice.aggregate([
                {
                    "$match": {
                        collectibleId: collectible_id,
                        "date": {
                            $gte: new Date(new Date().getTime() - (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000))
                        }
                    }
                },
            ])]
        }
    }
```

This is working fine for most periods, but as I enter large periods like '90' I'm getting the error

```
"message": "Float cannot represent non numeric value: Infinity",
```

I assume this is most likely an issue with the data and the value being something other than expected ? However it does work fine on the REST api and pipes into a graphing package just fine, is there a way I can allow or skip this value to return my results regardless of this entity?

Thanks,

Comment: Either (a) this error is coming from mongo or (b) your mongo query is returning `Infinity` as a value and your GraphQL type for that variable (`low`) is a float - a float cannot represent Infinity. You may need to define a custom scalar type that can deal with Infinity. Have you tried running the mongo query by itself in the mongo CLI?